# How to Transfer Datagrid Value of one form to TextBoxes of another form?

Tags: vb.net

I cant somehow figure why it can't transfer the data with no errors

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    Dim pinfo As New Employee_Personal_Info()
    pinfo.ShowDialog()

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        Employee_Personal_Info.TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("emp_firstname").Value.ToString

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Put the `ShowDialog()` after the `End If`

Comment: @kiLLua still the same result

Comment: @MahendranNadesan i'm not getting any errors. The system is running but the data is not transferring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you're displaying the form before passing it the data, the issue is that you are setting the `Text` of a `TextBox` on the default instance of that form, not the instance you created.  This:

```
Employee_Personal_Info.TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("emp_firstname").Value.ToString
```

should be this:

```
pinfo.TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("emp_firstname").Value.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass via globle variable like

public text as string

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
text=row.Cells("emp_firstname").Value.ToString
End Sub